# How to convert the date time format of 24 hours to 12 hours format

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting a date from the php file that is in 24 hours format like this

2015-02-19 22:39:00.000000  and I want convert this time format to 12 hours format like this 2015-02-19 10:39:00 PM, How can I achieve this using js or php ...

Comment: please put some code,how you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can achieve that like this : `$time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime($yourStringTime));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2015-02-19 22:39:00.000000'; 
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime($date));
```

Outputs:

```
2015-02-19 10:39:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = strtotime('2015-02-19 22:39:00.000000');
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s A',$d);
```

gives:

```
2015-02-19 10:39:00 PM
```